# Sharepoint workflow based on user status

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a condition (using Sharepoint designer) which says

> "if there is any engineer whose status = Available, assign the task to
>   that particular engineer. Also, change the engineer status to
>   unavailable after assigning the task. "

What steps do I need to do to make such a condition in Sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Useful Sharepoint Designer Activities; especially its [Lookup User Info](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lookup%20user%20info&referringTitle=Home)

This will not solve your particular case; but it might be a good start. I think you will have to either create a custom activity (this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629922(office.12).aspx) explains it) or [create your own workflow in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc936628(office.12).aspx)